# Android background service doesn't work on release mode?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, alarmmanager, background-service

I created an app with periodic background service (with alarm manager), this service launch every x minutes, so until now, everything is fine, I can start or stop my service without any problems.. until I deployed the app with release mode, after that whatever I start the service the app crashes!

This is my code..

**Start/Stop service from shared project**

```
DependencyService.Get<IAndroidNotifications>().StartNotificationsService();

DependencyService.Get<IAndroidNotifications>().StopNotificationsService();
```

**Notifications class**

```
public void StartNotificationsService()
{
//Start Notifications Service
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationsService));
context.StartService(myIntent);


//Show Snackbar message
Activity activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
Android.Views.View activityRootView = 
activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
Snackbar.Make(activityRootView, "Notifications on", 
Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
}

public void StopNotificationsService()
{
//Stop Notifications Service
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotificationsService));
context.StopService(myIntent);


//Show Snackbar message
Activity activity = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity;
Android.Views.View activityRootView = 
activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
Snackbar.Make(activityRootView, "Notifications off", 
Snackbar.LengthLong).Show();
}

public bool CheckNotificationsService()
{
ActivityManager manager = 
(ActivityManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
foreach (var service in manager.GetRunningServices(int.MaxValue))
{
    string x = service.Service.ClassName;
    if (service.Service.ClassName == "com.TestApp.NotificationsService") 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

private void StartAlarm(bool isRepeating)
{
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
Intent myIntent;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;


myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationsAlarm));
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);


if (!isRepeating)
{
    manager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 3000, 
pendingIntent);
}
else
{
    manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() 
+ 3000, 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}

}
}
```

**Notification service**

```
[Service
(Name = "com.TestApp.NotificationsService",
Label = "Service Notifications")]
class NotificationsService : Service
{
AlarmManager manager;
Intent myIntent;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
{
   return null;
}

//[return: GeneratedEnum]
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, 
StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
//return base.OnStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
manager = (AlarmManager)GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);



myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(NotificationsAlarm));
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

manager.SetRepeating(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 
1000, 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);


//Toast.MakeText(this, "Greating from our first service", 
ToastLength.Long).Show();
return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
}

public override void OnDestroy()
{
base.OnDestroy();
pendingIntent.Cancel();
manager.Cancel(pendingIntent);
}

}
}
```

**Broadcast receiver**

```
namespace TestApp.Droid
{
[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
public class NotificationsAlarm : BroadcastReceiver
{
static Random random = new Random();
int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 1000);

InfosAPI _infosAPI;
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Long).Show();

//something else here
}

}
}
```

any suggestions plz? thanks

Comment: If you're looking for help with a crash, post the full stack trace from logcat.

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: @GabeSechan thnkx for your fast comment, is there a stack trace on the release mode ? as I said while debugging the background service start successfully I didn't face any problem, but the app crashes only in the release mode.

Comment: @CoderCharmander

Comment: @Arselan Yes, the logcat always has a stack trace.